# Selenium find element

Tags: c#, selenium

So i created 2 generic functions for `FindElement` and `FindElements`:

```
public class Find
{
    public static IWebElement Element(IWebDriver driver, Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> expectedCondtions, 
        By locator, IWebElement finder = null, int timeOutInSeconds = 120)
    {
        WebDriverWait webDriverWait = CreateWebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds);
        webDriverWait.Until(expectedCondtions);

        if (finder != null)
            return finder.FindElement(locator);
        return driver.FindElement(locator);
    }

    public static ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> Elements(IWebDriver driver, Func<IWebDriver, ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>> expectedCondtions, 
        By locator, IWebElement finder = null, int timeOutInSeconds = 120)
    {
        WebDriverWait webDriverWait = CreateWebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds);
        webDriverWait.Until(expectedCondtions);

        if (finder == null)
            return driver.FindElements(locator);
        return finder.FindElements(locator);

    }

    private static WebDriverWait CreateWebDriverWait(IWebDriver driver, int timeOutInSeconds)
    {
        WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOutInSeconds));
        webDriverWait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
        return webDriverWait;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
IWebElement element =
    Find.Element(
    driver,
    ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("bla bla")),
    By.CssSelector("bla bla"));
```

As you can see i am send my `locator` twice to my `function` so my question is there is some way to send it only once ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your intent it is to write some generally applicable functions to make your code cleaner. This is a good thing in concept but I think in this case it doesn't achieve what you've hoped. I see a number of people wanting to do things like this. They want to create a wrapper around the simple methods provided by Selenium but in the end they haven't simplified their code, they have made it more complicated, added another layer of stuff in the call stack, potentially introduced bugs, and created a proprietary API that anyone that uses your code base will have to learn instead of just using basic Selenium commands. When every element find goes through a single function, any bugs or intermittency issues introduced by that function are seen in every single script in your suite.

A simple comparison:

Using your `Find` method

```
IWebElement e = Find.Element(Driver, ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("#checkboxes > input")), By.CssSelector("#checkboxes > input"), null, 10);
```

The Selenium only way

```
IWebElement e = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("#checkboxes > input")));
```

Using your methods isn't really cleaner in the end. I would go further in the Selenium-only way and do something like this to reuse the wait which makes the code that much cleaner.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement e = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("#checkboxes > input")));
IWebElement e2 = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("checkboxes")));
```

and because the `Until()` returns the element, you can chain actions like `.Click()`

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("#checkboxes > input"))).Click();
```

If you use the page object model (which, in general, you should), you would store your locators and then use them like below which makes the code even cleaner.

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(checkboxLocator)).Click();
```

Having said that, I would rewrite these like this

```
public class Find
{
    public static IWebElement Element(WebDriverWait wait, Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> expectedCondition)
    {
        return wait.Until(expectedCondition);
    }
    public static IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> Elements(WebDriverWait wait, Func<IWebDriver, IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>> expectedCondition)
    {
        return wait.Until(expectedCondition);
    }
}
```

The `Until()` method returns the found element(s), so you can just return the return which saves having to find things twice and eliminates the need for sending the locator twice.

I removed the `WebDriverWait()` you were creating in the methods because you really should be reusing a single instance. I don't know about you but I generally don't need 10 different wait times, I use maybe a couple. Declare those in your test script and pass them around.

I removed the `finder` element because it shouldn't be needed. You can easily create a single locator using CSS selectors that finds child elements.

In `CreateWebDriverWait()`, you don't need to ignore `NoSuchElementException`, it's already built in. So, this function can be reduced to

```
private static WebDriverWait CreateWebDriverWait(IWebDriver driver, int timeOutInSeconds)
{
    return new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOutInSeconds));
}
```

which at that point you have to ask yourself why is `Find.CreateWebDriverWait()` better than `new WebDriverWait()`? What are you gaining by writing this separate method? By having a separate method to create a `WebDriverWait`, you are also creating a new instance each time even if the timeout is 10s, especially true in `Element()` and `Elements()`. So, I omitted it from my code.

Comment: This was very comprehensive explanation, thanks a lot.